# How can I see all the key-value pairs in the `myShape.Cells()`?

Tags: vba, visio

I'm recently programming with the VB in the Visio.
I'm really curious about the `myShape.Cells("Width")` and `myShape.Cells("PinX")`, I mean the `.Cells("...")` part of the code.  My program has used them very many times.
I want to know more about them, but I can't find any specific explanation about this.

**Who definites it**, and what are **all of the key-value pairs** in the `.Cells()`.
I've seen someones in this site using `someShape.Cells["Width"]` to point to the value of the *shape's width*.

So:

1. I want to know if the `.Cells()` is an collection or map(dictionary) in reality. Please give me some explanation or files that I can read for help.
2. I've tried to put the `myShape.Cells` or `myShape.Cells()` in the watch window, but it didn't work. It told me something wrong..
   So How can I have a look at all the key-value pairs in the `.Cells()`, it will be a great help to give me some codes that I can use to show the key-value pairs in the immediate window.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: The VB and The vba are 2 very different things.  Pick one tag or the other (probably the vba)

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of accessing ShapeSheet cells in Visio.  One is by name, using the [Shape.Cells (or CellsU)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff768120.aspx) method you mention, and the other is by index using [Shape.CellsSRC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff767394.aspx).  The second method reveals how cells are structured, by Section, Row and Column.  Note that slightly confusingly, the SRC structure is not necessarily an exact replica of the cells you can see when you open the ShapeSheet in the UI, which is organised into something that's a little more user friendly.

The SRC indices are usually expressed as enums, which you can [look up in the SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj945060.aspx) along with the cell Name equivilent.

So to answer your questions more directly:

1. *Is .Cells a collection* - not one that you can call and retrieve all values.  You can loop through the cells using CellsSRC but you'll discover that the cells are not necessarily contiguous, plus there are a number of unnamed or internal cells that you can't use via the api.  For further details you might find this link useful https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa201764%28v=office.10%29.aspx
2. *myShape.Cells() doesn't work* - The cells method takes a single parameter, which is the string name of the cell.  This is often, but not always, the name you see in the ShapeSheet window.  Otherwise you have to look up the name in the docs - [Cells reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/jj945060.aspx)

One last point is that you should try and use the `CellsU` method rather than the `Cells` one.  The former accesses the cell names using universal syntax where the latter uses local syntax, which may differ across different locales.